# Creating a link in linked lists in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, malloc, nodes

Here is the code to create a link in the list which i read off the internet to try understand linked lists in c:

```
//insert link at first location

    void insertFirst(int key, int data) {
        //create a link
        struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    link->key = key;
    link->data = data;

    //point it to old first node
    link->next = head;

    //point first to new first node
    head = link;
}
```

I am really not understanding how the following line works as a whole:

```
struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

and more specifically:

```
(struct node*)
```

because my understanding is that the asterisk must come before the pointer name and yet its at the end of the struct name. Please correct me if I'm wrong and please if you can, explain how this works?

Comment: You do not need the cast.

Comment: Properly `struct node *link = malloc (sizeof *link);` then `if (link == NULL) { /* handle error */ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting the return value of `malloc` is unnecessary.

As per standard **7.22.3.4**

> The malloc function returns either a null pointer or a pointer to the
>   allocated space.

You should check its return value to know whether it succeeded or not.

#### What malloc does?

The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and whose value is indeterminate.

*my understanding is that the asterisk must come before the pointer name and yet its at the end of the struct name*

Here you are not dereferencing anything. Rather you are typecasting. (which is again I would repeat that unnecessary).

`struct node*` here is a type of the pointer variable. Same way `int` or `double` is a type, this is also a type.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have to create database of a students having some entities.

```
 struct node
    {
       int id;
       char name [100];
    };
```

Next thing,

```
struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

How above line works ? you need to create one node or `memory`, So how will you create it, use `malloc()`. Next things `how much memory` you are going to create , equal to `total size` of your `data members` of structure, so for that its using

```
 struct node *link = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

here `link` is nothing but name of dynamic memory we created to put some data into that. once memory is created put some data into memory.

```
   scanf("%d %s\n",&link->id,link->name);
```

similarly you can do above task no of times.

typecasting is not compulsory or not advised to do. So below statement is correct.

struct node *link = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

Comment: *Assume you have to create database of 3 students having some entities.* Okay, but where are you using this 3 value?

Comment: @MFisherKDX  I mention just for examples, the guy who asked can use array of structure & then allocate memory of same.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a linked list you have to allocate the units -in your case :

**struct node**

so either you pre-allocate the memory for the list or dynamically allocate them every time you add a node to the list, the memoery for the node has to be recruited from somewhere, in this case  - malloc does that.

Hope that helps